# something is not right with console.time();

Tags: javascript, console

I am testing my javascript's speed using the `console.time();` method, so it logs the loading time of a function on load.

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
    var images = $('img');

    console.time('testing');
    var imagesObj = images.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < imagesObj; i++ ) {  
        var lowres = images.eq(i).attr('src'),
        highres = lowres.replace(".", "_2x.");
        images.eq(i).attr('src', highres);
    }
    console.timeEnd('testing');
}
```

But every time I reload the page it gives me a pretty different value. Should it have this behaviour? Shouldn't it give me a consistent value?

I have loaded it 5 times in a row and the values are the following:

- 5.051 ms
- 4.977 ms
- 8.009 ms
- 5.325 ms
- 6.951 ms

I am running this on XAMPP and in Chrome btw.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show use some code sample ?

Comment: Pretty different as in several significant orders of magnitude? Page load speeds vary enormously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.time/endTime` is working correctly and the timing *does* indeed fluctuate by a *tiny* amount.

*However*, when dealing with such *small* numbers - the timings are all less than 1/100 of a second! - the deviation is irrelevant and can be influenced by a huge number of factors.

Answer (score 1):

There is always variation, could be caused by a number of things.

- server responding slightly slower (hat can also block other parts of the browser)
- your processor is doing something in the mean time
- your processor clocked down to save power
- random latency in the network
- browser extension doing something in the background

Also, Firefox has a system that intelligently tries to optimize javascript execution, in most cases it will perform better but it is somewhat random.